# Добавить префикс к адресам ссылок

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Всем привет!

Помогите решить вопрос с регуляркой на php.
**СУТЬ:** Нужно в контенте находить все ссылки, и добавлять приставку **/uk/**, чтобы получилось `<a href="/uk/bla-bla/bla"></a>`, и если находит ссылки уже с приставкой **/uk/** - `<a href="/uk/bla-bla/bla"></a>`, то не добавлять(чтобы не получилось `<a href="/uk/uk/bla-bla/bla">`).
сайт на ВП.

САМА РЕГУЛЯРКА:

```
$content = preg_replace("/<a(.*)href=\"([^\/uk\/])\"(.*)\/a>/","<a\\$1href=\"/uk\\$2\"\\$3/a>", $post->post_content);

$content = preg_replace("!<a(.*?)href=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)\/a>!si","<a\\1href=\"/uk\\2\"\\3/a>", $post_c->post_content);
```

Я не силен в регулярках, что не делал не получаеться(( Получилось только добавлять **/uk/**
Заранее спасибо большое Всем.

Comment: Используйте утверждения http://ru2.php.net/manual/ru/regexp.reference.assertions.php вот эту часть мануала: `.. Утверждения касательно предшествующего текста начинаются с (?<= для положительных утверждений и (?<! для отрицающих. Например, (?<!foo)bar найдёт вхождения "bar", которым не предшествует "foo".`

Comment: данный вариант, также интересен, как сделаю, отпишусь. Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

выражение

```
$text = preg_replace('/href="\/(?!uk\/)(.+?)"/im', 'href="/uk/$1"', $text);
```

заменит

```
/uk/bla-bla/bla   =>   /uk/bla-bla/bla
/ku/bla-bla/bla   =>   /uk/ku/bla-bla/bla
/bla-bla/bla      =>   /uk/bla-bla/bla
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло

Comment: @webEugene тогда отметьте ответ как правильный :)

Comment: ответ неполноценный эту строку не берет `<a href='/ku/bla-bla/bla'>`.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan не работает поскольку кавычки в вашем случае одинарные. в исходном вопросе кавычки исключительно двойные, так что решение соответствует задаче.

Comment: В исходом вопросе пример строки, и оно может быть и таким как я написал. если в вопросе пример задан, это не значит что правильный ответ если строго примеру соответствует.

Comment: @RazmikGalstyan если в вопросе что-то не указано, значит это плохой вопрос и его надо конкретизировать. Если хотите фантазировать по поводу формата входных данных, то флаг вам в руки, и как вы мне в других дискуссиях не раз говорили, можете написать свой ответ.

Comment: Конечно это ваше мнение, Я показал дефект.